# Creating DTM from COPC LAZ Files using PDAL

Tags: raster, dem, pdal, copc

I have been running into issues with PDAL and a Batch script I am running.

I have a series of Cloud Optimized Point Clouds (COPC) and I am looking to generate a DTM from them.

I am using the following Pipeline and Windows Batch.

**PIPELINE**

```
*{
    "pipeline": [
        {
            "type":"readers.copc"
        },
        {
            "type":"filters.range",
            "limits":"Classification[2:2]"
        },
        {
            "gdaldriver":"GTiff",
            "output_type":"idw",
            "resolution" :"2.0",
            "default_srs": "EPSG:2157",
            "type": "writers.gdal"
        }
    ]
}*
```

**BATCH**

```
*@echo=off
for %%f in ("*copc.laz") do (
pdal pipeline raster_pipeline.json \ --readers.copc.filename=".%%~nxf" \--writers.gdal.filename=".dtm/%%~nf.tif"
)
pause*
```

I keep getting an error:

**PDAL: Unable to open '.284000_258000.copc.laz'. File does not exist.**

I have a feeling it is to do with the dot in front of the filename, but if it is not in the batch I get the following error

**PDAL: Stage option '--readers.copc.filename=' not valid.**

Can you provide any help on this?

Comment: Does the command work without your batch for a single named file? If it does the problem is in the batch file and you can try to find help from stackoverflow.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for your responce. Apparently my script dosent work with a single pointcloud, I will look at it a little more and If I cant find a solution, I will do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the batch was the problem. With a little tweaking it has worked.
The solution is.....

```
@echo=off 
for %%f in ("*copc.laz") do ( pdal pipeline "raster_pipeline.json" --readers.copc.filename="%%~nxf" \ --writers.gdal.filename="dtm/%%~nf.tif" ) 
pause
```

Thanks again to @user30184 for pointing me in the right direction. Testing it with a single file helped me to diagnose the issue.